# Django: How to change default SignUp fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-2.0

I am struggling with changing default UserCreationForm - I was able to add one additional field by creating child class:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    display_name = forms.CharField(max_length=32, help_text='Your display name')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'display_name', 'password1', 'password2', )

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.profile.display_name = form.cleaned_data.get('display_name')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('user/home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return header.views.show(request, 'userpanel/register.html', context={'form': form})
```

Together with template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text | safe }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p style="color: red">{{ error | safe }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

I was able to create following page:

[image]

But I have the problem with changing description texts on a page. Now, if I would like to change *Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.* to something else, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Listing all properties of a form by:

```
form = SignUpForm()
for d in dir(form):
    print(d)
```

I found, by trials and errors, that you can list fields of the form:

```
form = SignUpForm()
for d in form.fields:
    print('field name:', d)
    print('field label:', form.fields[d].label)
    print('field text:', form.fields[d].help_text)
    print("")
```

returns:

```
field name: username
field label: Username
field text: Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.

field name: display_name
field label: None
field text: Your display name

field name: password1
field label: Password
field text: <ul><li>Your password can&#39;t be too similar to your other personal information.</li><li>Your password mus
t contain at least 8 characters.</li><li>Your password can&#39;t be a commonly used password.</li><li>Your password can&
#39;t be entirely numeric.</li></ul>

field name: password2
field label: Password confirmation
field text: Enter the same password as before, for verification.
```

I can easily alter those fields by writting:

```
x = form.fields['username']
x.label = "foo"
x.help_text = "bar"
```

and I got:

[image]

Comment: Mark you answer accepted to tag the question as solved !

Comment: I can do it in two days.